# Define a reference site for the history.back button

Tags: javascript, php, html

We want to have a back button in our site
but history.back in javascript does not help us.
We need this function only run on the site and if the user comes  from other site, clicking the return button on the previous site should not return.

In fact, we want a return button to run on our site only.
 my code is

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-anim"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i><span class="btn-text">Back</span></a>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: If the user came from Google or another site, we would move it to another page

Comment: I had to review your "question", and I still don't know what the question is. You should edit your post to make that crystal clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code checks the history of back button of the browser on its `click` event:

```
$('#backbtn').click(function () {
    if (document.referrer.includes(window.location.hostname)) {
        window.history.back();
    } else {
        window.location.href = "/your/path";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**This only works for your own made back button and won't work with the browser back button**

There is two ways to achieve that: a simple but not always reliable method and a complex one but always good.

### 1- The simple method

You use `document.referrer` and ensure the domain is yours before calling `history.back()`.

### 2- The complex method

You could register a JavaScript function on page load to get the first URL the internaut land which you could store using [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method). Before calling the back function, you could ensure this is not that page. Though, this idea is not complete as the user could probably have landed on this page twice. i.e. Home->Product->Home. I'll let you search for further code that would let you counter this problem.